# Flashforge adventurer 3 will not home or calibrate

Tags: troubleshooting, firmware, flashforge-adventurer-3

I had a piece of filament break off in the tube and could not unload it so I removed the extruder and pulled out the piece. Reloaded filament and started to recalibrate. The head went to left and tried to keep going. It made a horrible thumping and would not stop until I turned the unit off. I then tried to home it, same result. Tried to reset to factory settings then home it and same result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the end stop of the X-axis (i.e. the minimum end stop on the left) has moved/bent/broken/un-connected.

Please look into [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/19701/5) of question [Flashforge Adventurer 3 - how to replace X-axis endstop](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/19699/flashforge-adventurer-3-how-to-replace-x-axis-endstop). The X end stop is a module inside the print head, please look if the connector is dislodged or something.