# Flashforge Adventurer 3 - how to replace X-axis endstop

Tags: homing, endstop, flashforge-adventurer-3

I found a similar question in the forum but now need assistance on how to replace the X-axis endstop. I have been scouring for videos and haven't found one yet.  Can anyone help me?

The printer turns on, preheats but as soon as I choose a print, it goes to the right and just continues to run. It only stops when I turn it off.

I did a factory reset and no luck. I ordered the new parts but really don't know where to start. It looks like the wires for the endstop run into the body of the machine so it looks like I will be taking the whole thing apart. I am quite nervous about this.

Comment: Hi Samantha, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please link to the question you found.

Comment: I can't find a video that shows how to replace it on my specific type of 3D printer - Flashforge Adventurer 3.  I have not removed it yet b/c I don't know how to get to it.

Comment: I've added an [answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/19701/), please look at the [video I linked](https://youtu.be/x-TyfVOtsg4?t=220), I think it is clear how you need to proceed to replace the part. Disclaimer; I don't own the printer, please be sensible, I'm not responsible for damages. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "how to" to replace the X end stop; this post is meant as a description of the location of the X-axis end stop.

End stops are generally located on the minimum of the axis, but there are exceptions, e.g. Ultimaker has the Z-axis end stop at the bottom, this is the maximum. For the X-axis, end stops can be located on the print head, but more commonly found on the minimum value of the X-axis. The Flashforge Adventurer 3 has the X-axis end stop mounted in the print head.

The image below shows the overview of the X gantry:

[image]

Note the flag on the right (encircled in red):

[image]

The flag enters (on [homing](/q/18453)) the rectangular slot on the top rigt, see below:

[image]

So, this is where the X-axis end stop is located. This implies that the print head needs to be disassembled.

The X-axis end stop module can be found online as a replacement part, the back looks like this

[image]

and the front like this:

[image]

It appears that you can [take off the top of the printhead cover](https://youtu.be/x-TyfVOtsg4?t=220):

[image]

You will instantly see that the end stop module can be found there! It takes 2 screws to replace it (and some connectors!).